# How to configure Table of contents itself?

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

The aim is to manually configure the page(s) the TOC itself.
The font size of TOC name. 
Also I need to configure pagestyle of this(these) page(s)

The components by using `\titlecontents` I've already did.
The next code in .cls doesnt't works

```
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\newpage \fontsize{16}{16}
                               \thispagestyle{fancy}
                             }
```

Similar declaration for chapters works perfectly

```
\renewcommand\chapter{\newpage
                    \thispagestyle{fancy}%
                    \global\@topnum 0 %
                    \@afterindenttrue% 
                    \secdef{\@chapter}{\@schapter}}
```

Comment: And which document class do you use?

Comment: Actually it is my own. But uses \LoadClass[a4paper]{report}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package to easily do this; redefining `\cfttoctitlefont` you can change the font attributes for the title, and using `\tocloftpagestyle{<style>}` you select the page style. A simple example with some settings just for the example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{Center}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont\bfseries}
\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{test section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you're amazing, man

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina \tocloftpagestyle{fancy} state empty page only for the first page of the TOC. How can I assign \pagestyle{empty} for all  TOC-pages with tocloft?